# How to check if activex object is created in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I was having trouble with a PDF object that I was using to get page numbers,

```
Set AcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")    'Acrobat Exchange
Set AcroExchPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
```

The code would fail on this line on some machines.

How do I have it fail gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a graceful way to handle the error, that prompts the user to install the required application

```
On Error Resume Next
Set AcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")    'Acrobat Exchange
Set AcroExchPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
'AcroExchApp.Show ' Show the Acrobat Exchange window
On Error GoTo 0
'check if activex pdf object exists
If AcroExchApp Is Nothing Or AcroExchPDDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Adobe Acrobat Pro Activex control not found." & _
        vbCrLf & "Please install Adobe Acrobat Pro and try again"
    Exit Sub
End If
```